# Is Ubuntu abandoning its phone efforts?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, canonical, support, unity8

I received an email about this today. Does anyone know anything about Ubuntu stopping their support for Ubuntu Touch? Will the phone and tablet that I have not be supported any more, or receive any new/more software releases?

It is a shame as I really do like Ubuntu Touch

- [Ubuntu Abandons Its Phone Efforts](https://www.huewire.com/ubuntu-abandons-its-phone-efforts-will-switch-back-to-gnome/) (huewire.com)
- [Ubuntu Unity is dead: Desktop will switch back to GNOME next year](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/04/ubuntu-unity-is-dead-desktop-will-switch-back-to-gnome-next-year/) (arstechnica.com)

Comment: Regardless, referring to the [support schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) should alleviate any immediate concerns you may have.

Comment: YES concern is what I had when I read this too!

Comment: Check the version you are running against the schedule. What the buzz is about appears to be the dropping of Unity in favor of gnome in 18.04 LTS release as I recall. I wouldn't expect this plan for the future should have no impact on the current support schedule. You might find more information here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/GetHelp

Comment: So 17.10 and 17.04 are still gonna be on Unity 7? Not 8?

Comment: "it is something that a fair few people in this community will want to talk about." Open-ended discussions are not on-topic here. You should use chat for that.

Comment: Also, link to the original post: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence/, instead of an article which quotes another article which in turn quotes the original.

Comment: The video shows a fair bit of the functionality that the tablet currently has. I have been unable to find any reference to another Touch release. Tablets only have a life of 3 (ish) years, so it would be good it they were supported till then.

Comment: It does look like it I true. I just hope that they respect that some people did decide to go against the grain and buy Touch tablets and phones. Therefore they need to be looked after till the life of their devices.

Comment: I keep on getting updates  for the web apps and paps that I have which is nice. I personally think that the basics should of been sorted out first and then extra functionality built into it then. I went to Touch and discarded my Andriod phone. However, not having g what people use (e.g. Whats app and a supported email client) was not the way to get the numbers over, which is what was needed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Canonical (the company behind Ubuntu) is no longer developing for phones and tablets. In addition, in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, the default desktop shell will switch from Unity 7 to GNOME Shell. Development on Unity 8, Mir and phone/desktop convergence will come to an end. Existing phone and desktop releases will be supported for their normal lifecycle.

This was officially announced in a post from Mark Shuttleworth, founder of Ubuntu and Canonical, on the Ubuntu website: https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence/

Since these are free software projects, someone else can take over development and maintenance. Right now (April 2017) these communities are looking into it:

- [UBports](https://ubports.com), porting what used to be "Ubuntu Touch" to multiple mobile devices
- [yunit](https://yunit.io), continuing development of Unity 8, with a desktop focus
- and there is possible collaboration between the two

...at this stage the discussion is mostly technical and it is yet to be seen if these communities have enough resources for long-term development.

Comment: This is such a shame as I personally like the system. I have had better success with it on my tablet, than on the phone. However, the idea that they will be supported for their normal life cycle needs to be cleared up. How long are they saying the "normal life cycle" is and what is included in support.

Comment: @PhilUK I think that's worth a separate question and/or contacting your vendor or Canonical directly - if you don't mind fiddling, I've added links to two development communities above

Comment: thanks for the update. It is good to hear that Touch may live on past the shock announcement. I just wish it would have more of the things that people want. I remember a few months ago that it was said that Touch has Telegram. That is great, but when the rest of the work is using Whatsapp, then you need that too, That is only one example.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems like they are. Development on Ubuntu Phone seems to be coming to an end since it never really took off in the first place.

Mark Coppock at Digital Trends has written an article here talking about this: http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/canonical-ending-unity8-phone-and-convergence-development/

Comment: Hopefully the Librem 5 will fill the gap and be a phone you can run any OS on, as you can on your computer https://puri.sm/shop/librem-5/